# GET DATA FROM TXT SUM GROUP BY AND SUBTRACT

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, subtraction, sumifs

Trying to get data from txt file which contains buys and sells like in the format below.
I want to group by items and subtract each other.

I made three queries like totalin and totalout and stock but when I subtract out from in, some items are missing which has not been sold.

This is the data table

```
+------+---------+--------+
| TYPE |  ITEM   | AMOUNT |
+------+---------+--------+
| BUY  | APPLE   |    100 |
| BUY  | ORANGE  |    100 |
| BUY  | APPLE   |    200 |
| BUY  | ORANGE  |    200 |
| SELL | APPLE   |     50 |
| SELL | APPLE   |     50 |
| SELL | ORANGE  |    100 |
| SELL | ORANGE  |    100 |
| BUY  | COCONUT |     50 |
| SELL | BANANE  |     30 |
+------+---------+--------+
```

I want this output

```
+---------+--------+
|  ITEM   | AMOUNT |
+---------+--------+
| APPLE   |    200 |
| BANANE  |    -30 |
| COCONUT |     50 |
| ORANGE  |    100 |
+---------+--------+
```

I made 3 queries for the result that i want, but unfortunately I am stuck.

Here is my queries

QUERY 1 TOTAL IN:
   `SELECT DATA.TYPE, DATA.ITEM, Sum(DATA.AMOUNT) AS TOTALIN
    FROM DATA
    GROUP BY DATA.TYPE, DATA.ITEM
    HAVING (((DATA.TYPE)="BUY"));`

QUERY 2 TOTAL OUT:
   `SELECT DATA.TYPE, DATA.ITEM, Sum(DATA.AMOUNT) AS TOTALOUT
    FROM DATA
    GROUP BY DATA.TYPE, DATA.ITEM
    HAVING (((DATA.TYPE)="SELL"));`

QUERY 3 STOCK:
   `SELECT DATA.ITEM, [BUY]![TOTAL_IN]-[SELL]![TOTAL_OUT] AS STOK
FROM (DATA INNER JOIN BUY ON DATA.ITEM = BUY.ITEM) INNER JOIN SELL ON DATA.ITEM = SELL.ITEM
GROUP BY DATA.ITEM, [BUY]![TOTAL_IN]-[SELL]![TOTAL_OUT];`

How can I made a query which shows the rest as stock.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sum in one go like:

```
SELECT ITEM, 
       Sum(iif(data.type = "BUY", AMOUNT, -AMOUNT)) AS Stock
    FROM DATA
    GROUP BY ITEM;
```

Comment: Thank you, i just didn't think in that way. Does 'CASE WHEN' clause work in access?

Comment: I don't use access but AFAIK case when doesn't exist in access. If it is not too late, prefer using something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of SELL as -ve and BUY as +ve Amount.

Then the query becomes as follows

```
select item
       ,sum(case when type='BUY' then Amount
                 when type='SELL' then -Amount
             end) as Amount
  from data_table
 group by item
```

Answer (score 0):

In MsAccess, you can apply an if-logic block using the `iif function` and run the query in one step as below.

```
SELECT item,   
SUM(iif ([type] = "SELL", (-1 * Amount), Amount)) as amounts   
FROM data   
GROUP BY item
```